# Running docker containers only local behind csf firewall

Tags: iptables, firewall, docker, csf

I want to access docker containers only locally behind the csf firewall on a remote Ubuntu server. I changed the `DOCKER` settings options in `/etc/csf/csf.conf` to `1` to allow docker to change iptable rules.

If I am starting my container with `-p 8000:8000`, the port `8000` is exposed to the whole world (I can access the website with `mydomain.com:8000`, as expected, but not what I wanted). If I am starting the container with `-p 127.0.0.1:8000:8000` I can't access it with `mydomain.com:8000` (which is great), but in both cases calling `localhost:8000` will result in an `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` error in Chrome or `curl: (52) Empty reply from server` in the terminal.

Tried it with different containers and different ports. After disabling csf, it works without the empty-reply-error so is must be related to csf.

How to configure csf to expose and access docker container over specific ports only locally?

Sidenote: I am working remotely on the server with `ssh admin@mydomain.com -L 8000:localhost:8000`.

Comment: thanks for your question, before this moment i exposed to public the port, now the ports only be allowed by the nginx proxy

Answer (score 6):

Had the same scenario.  Found that packets from lo to docker0 were being blocked by CSF's OUTPUT ruleset.

Resolved by adding "docker0" to ETH_DEVICE_SKIP, which causes CSF to add a blanket ACCEPT rule to the INPUT and OUTPUT chains for this interface.  This should not be a problem since AFAIK docker0 should never be bound to a physical interface, but someone with more Docker experience might know otherwise.