# Newbie: How to add mod_sec rule exception for specific use-case

Tags: linux, security, mod-security, csf

maybe someone with experience or basic knowledge that knows what they're doing (unlike me :)) can help....

Currently, I have Ubuntu 20.04 installation with OpenLitespeed and Cyberpanel.

I've installed Plausible Analytics via docker container on pa.domain1.com and noticed that when I visit the address pa.domain1.com/domain2.com (basically the URL or the domain2 I'm tracking) it gives me a mod_sec log entry:

```
ModSecurity: Warning. Matched "Operator `Within' with parameter `.asa/ .asax/ .ascx/ .axd/ .backup/ .bak/ .bat/ .cdx/ .cer/ .cfg/ .cmd/ .com/ .config/ .conf/ .cs/ .csproj/ .csr/ .dat/ .db/ .dbf/ .dll/ .dos/ .htr/ .htw/ .ida/ .idc/ .idq/ .inc/ .ini/ .key/ .licx/ .ln (150 characters omitted)' against variable `TX:EXTENSION' (Value: `.com/' ) [file "/usr/local/lsws/conf/modsec/owasp-modsecurity-crs-3.0-master/rules/REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT.conf"] [line "1015"] [id "920440"] [rev ""] [msg "URL file extension is restricted by policy"] [data ".com"] [severity "2"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.2"] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-protocol"] [tag "paranoia-level/1"] [tag "OWASP_CRS"] [tag "capec/1000/210/272"] [tag "PCI/6.5.10"] [hostname "pa.domain1.com"] [uri "/domain2.com"] [unique_id "16959174363.819657"] [ref "o11,4o12,3v5,15o71,5t:urlDecodeUni,t:lowercase"]
ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Matched "Operator `Ge' with parameter `5' against variable `TX:ANOMALY_SCORE' (Value: `5' ) [file "/usr/local/lsws/conf/modsec/owasp-modsecurity-crs-3.0-master/rules/REQUEST-949-BLOCKING-EVALUATION.conf"] [line "80"] [id "949110"] [rev ""] [msg "Inbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (Total Score: 5)"] [data ""] [severity "2"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.2"] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-generic"] [hostname "pa.domain1.com"] [uri "/domain2.com"] [unique_id "16959174363.819657"] [ref ""]
```

And from that log I concluded that the rules 9 & 18 (REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT.conf & REQUEST-949-BLOCKING-EVALUATION.conf) are being tripped up, which I get. There is a different domain after the / and that does seem very dubious at first, but that is correct.

Hence, I've deactived rule 9 & 18. Now, I can then access the URL pa.domain1.com/domain2.com.

However, I **don't** want to leave these 2 rules deactivated as a whole, just create an exception. Luckily, for me as complete Linux noob, I can add a mod_sec rule in Cyberpanel and hit save.

**But I do not know what and how that rules is supposed to look like to create that rule. Ideally, it would be also be flexible enough where I don't have to add another rule for pa.domain1.com/domain3.com, pa.domain1.com/domain4.com etc. Can anyone let me know the rule that would whitelist my scenario?***

**Bonus points:**

Some what related (I think). In my plausible.env file, it requires port 127.0.0.1:8000:8000.
Currently, I have that port open (IN & OUT) in CSF. Otherwise, I cannot access the analytics site at pa.domain1.com. [This](https://serverfault.com/questions/1020400/running-docker-containers-only-local-behind-csf-firewall) did not seem to work. And from what I read one shouldn't leave ports wide open if not absolutely necessary. As this application runs via 127.0.0.1 shouldn't that be able to run without those ports open to the world?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude id 920440 and 949110 for pa.domain1.com only, then you can try adding the following to the REQUEST-900-EXCLUSION-RULES-BEFORE-CRS.conf file.

```
SecRule SERVER_NAME "pa\.domain1\.com$"
    "id:1001, phase:1, nolog,\
    ctl:ruleRemoveById=920440, \
    ctl:ruleRemoveById=949110"
```

Then restart the web server with the following command:

```
service lsws restart
```